# Vbscript copy files based on beginning letters

Tags: vbscript, copy, letters

I am trying to get this script to copy all files starting with "XX". Currently it only copies one file.

```
Dim objFSO, colFiles, objFile, strDestFolder, objNewestFile
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set colFiles = objFSO.GetFolder("C:\source")
strDestFolder = "C:\destination\"

For Each objFile In colFiles.Files
  If Left(objFile.Name, 2) = "XX" Then
  If objNewestFile = "" Then   
    Set objNewestFile = objFile  
  Else   
      If objNewestFile.DateLastModified < objFile.DateLastModified Then    
        Set objNewestFile = objFile   
      End If  
  End If
End If
Next

If Not objNewestFile Is Nothing Then 
objFSO.CopyFile objNewestFile.Path,strDestFolder,True
End If

WScript.Echo "Copied."
```

Comment: You are doing `CopyFile` outside your loop, so it can only copy the last `objNewestFile`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use wildcards `*` and `?` in [source] argument of FSO `.CopyFile` method.

So the code may look like:

```vbs
Dim objFSO
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
objFSO.CopyFile "C:\source\XX*.*", "C:\destination\", True
WScript.Echo "Copied."
```

Comment: Your code works like a charm. Thank you both for your time.